# Symfony 2 Twig UTF-8 Accents Encoding

Tags: symfony, encoding, special-characters, twig

This is a code exemple from my twig file

```
<h3>Some Data With accents é è ô</h3>
    {{ data_from_controller | raw }}
```

the text is replaced by special characters => `�`

but When Data is provided from database there is no problem with accents

My Encoding is UTF-8

Result :

```
<h3>Some Data With accents � � �</h3>
<span>data from database->controller exemple : é à è ... </span>
<span>data from controller without database : � � � ... </span>
```

Any one know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that in your IDE (netbeans, notepad++...) that you are UTF-8 compliant. It means that you have to be sure that each time you save your files, it saves it with the UTF-8 (Without BOM) encoding.

If your controller file are saved in a non UTF8 encoding, and twig is configured to display UTF8, it'll result in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<td>
    {{ report.name| raw | convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') }}
</td>
```